# HsqlException: incompatible data types in combination

Tags: spring, hsqldb, spring-data-rest

Since I moved my integration tests to an in-memory HSQLDB (want to avoid having to provide a proper MySQL everytime and clearing the database after every test), I am getting this error message everytime the CrudRepository#findById() method is called

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data types in combination
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.getAggregateType(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.hsqldb.types.Type.getAggregateType(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
```

and that's the case for `GET /ID`, `PATCH /ID` and `DELETE /ID` calls to the REST API (spring data rest). The outer exception is

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data types in combination in statement [select trainingre0_.id as id1_15_0_, trainingre0_.matching_rule_id as matching3_15_0_, trainingre0_.tenant as tenant2_15_0_, matchingru1_.id as id1_2_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode1_0_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode1_3_1_, matchingru1_.property as property2_3_1_, matchingru1_.value as value3_3_1_, matchingru1_.ignore_case as ignore_c1_6_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode2_6_1_, matchingru1_.property as property3_6_1_, matchingru1_.value as value4_6_1_, matchingru1_.clazz_ as clazz_1_, matchingru2_.composite_matching_rule_id as composit1_1_2_, matchingru3_.id as matching2_1_2_, matchingru3_.id as id1_2_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode1_0_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode1_3_3_, matchingru3_.property as property2_3_3_, matchingru3_.value as value3_3_3_, matchingru3_.ignore_case as ignore_c1_6_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode2_6_3_, matchingru3_.property as property3_6_3_, matchingru3_.value as value4_6_3_, matchingru3_.clazz_ as clazz_3_ from training_request_subscription trainingre0_ left outer join ( select id, mode, cast(null as varchar(100)) as property, cast(null as int) as value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 1 as clazz_ from composite_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 2 as clazz_ from number_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, ignore_case, 3 as clazz_ from string_matching_rule ) matchingru1_ on trainingre0_.matching_rule_id=matchingru1_.id left outer join composite_matching_rule_matching_rules matchingru2_ on matchingru1_.id=matchingru2_.composite_matching_rule_id left outer join ( select id, mode, cast(null as varchar(100)) as property, cast(null as int) as value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 1 as clazz_ from composite_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 2 as clazz_ from number_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, ignore_case, 3 as clazz_ from string_matching_rule ) matchingru3_ on matchingru2_.matching_rules_id=matchingru3_.id where trainingre0_.id=?]
```

but let me show you the domain model which hopefully makes it clearer:

**TrainingRequestSubscription** (the entity I that creates the error when read):

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ValidTrainingRequestSubscription
public class TrainingRequestSubscription extends AbstractBaseEntity implements TenantScoped {

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String tenant;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotNull
    private @NonNull MatchingRule matchingRule;

}
```

**MatchingRule**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
// @formatter:off
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = NumberMatchingRule.class, name = "number"), 
  @Type(value = StringMatchingRule.class, name = "string"),
  @Type(value = CompositeMatchingRule.class, name = "composite")
})
//@formatter:on
public abstract class MatchingRule extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract Set<String> getProperties();

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    public abstract String getType();

}
```

**NumberMatchingRule** (this is the implementation of matching rule I am testing with)

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class NumberMatchingRule extends MatchingRule {

    public static enum Mode {
        LESS, LESS_EQUAL, EQUAL, GREATER_EQUAL, GREATER
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Builder.Default
    private @NonNull Mode mode = Mode.EQUAL;

    @NotNull
    private @NonNull Double value;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private @NonNull String property;

    @Override
    public Set<String> getProperties() {
        return Set.of(property);
    }

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    public String getType() {
        return "number";
    }

}
```

It all works nicely on MySQL and the stack trace is not giving me any directions on what might be causing the problem. So I am relying on your experience here.

Maybe posting the repo itself is useful, too, since it could container @Query annotations that influence the behavior, but I only have on @Query on the findAll() method that should not be involved. In fact, tests that use findAll() succeed.

```
@CrossOrigin
public interface TrainingRequestSubscriptionRepo extends CrudRepository<TrainingRequestSubscription, UUID> {

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyScopeFor('trainingrequestsubscription', 'read')")
    @Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE CONCAT(e.tenant.id, '') IN ?#{security.getTenants('trainingrequestsubscription', 'r')} OR '*' IN ?#{security.getTenants('trainingrequestsubscription', 'r')}")
    @Override
    Set<TrainingRequestSubscription> findAll();

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyScopeFor('trainingrequestsubscription', 'read')")
    @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')")
    @Override
    Optional<TrainingRequestSubscription> findById(UUID id);

    // @formatter:off
    @PreAuthorize(
    "isFullyAuthenticated() and " +
    "(" +
        "(#entity.id == null and hasPermission(#entity, 'create'))" + " or " +
        "(#entity.id != null and hasPermission(#entity, 'update'))" +
    ")")
    // @formatter:on
    @Override
    <S extends TrainingRequestSubscription> S save(@Param("entity") S entity);

    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#entity, 'delete')")
    @Override
    void delete(@Param("entity") TrainingRequestSubscription entity);

}
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the comments, I ran HSQLDB in server mode with `--silent false` and `--trace true`` to see what the incoming request is:

```
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLPREPARE insert into number_matching_rule (mode, property, value, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLEXECUTE:1
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLFREESTMT:1
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLPREPARE insert into training_request_subscription (matching_rule_id, tenant, id) values (?, ?, ?)
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLEXECUTE:2
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLFREESTMT:2
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLENDTRAN:COMMIT
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:HSQLCLI:SETSESSIONATTR:
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:HSQLCLI:SETSESSIONATTR:
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:HSQLCLI:GETSESSIONATTR
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:HSQLCLI:SETSESSIONATTR:
[Server@2e0fa5d3]: 0:SQLCLI:SQLPREPARE select trainingre0_.id as id1_15_0_, trainingre0_.matching_rule_id as matching3_15_0_, trainingre0_.tenant as tenant2_15_0_, matchingru1_.id as id1_2_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode1_0_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode1_3_1_, matchingru1_.property as property2_3_1_, matchingru1_.value as value3_3_1_, matchingru1_.ignore_case as ignore_c1_6_1_, matchingru1_.mode as mode2_6_1_, matchingru1_.property as property3_6_1_, matchingru1_.value as value4_6_1_, matchingru1_.clazz_ as clazz_1_, matchingru2_.composite_matching_rule_id as composit1_1_2_, matchingru3_.id as matching2_1_2_, matchingru3_.id as id1_2_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode1_0_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode1_3_3_, matchingru3_.property as property2_3_3_, matchingru3_.value as value3_3_3_, matchingru3_.ignore_case as ignore_c1_6_3_, matchingru3_.mode as mode2_6_3_, matchingru3_.property as property3_6_3_, matchingru3_.value as value4_6_3_, matchingru3_.clazz_ as clazz_3_ from training_request_subscription trainingre0_ left outer join ( select id, mode, cast(null as varchar(100)) as property, cast(null as int) as value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 1 as clazz_ from composite_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 2 as clazz_ from number_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, ignore_case, 3 as clazz_ from string_matching_rule ) matchingru1_ on trainingre0_.matching_rule_id=matchingru1_.id left outer join composite_matching_rule_matching_rules matchingru2_ on matchingru1_.id=matchingru2_.composite_matching_rule_id left outer join ( select id, mode, cast(null as varchar(100)) as property, cast(null as int) as value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 1 as clazz_ from composite_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 2 as clazz_ from number_matching_rule union all select id, mode, property, value, ignore_case, 3 as clazz_ from string_matching_rule ) matchingru3_ on matchingru2_.matching_rules_id=matchingru3_.id where trainingre0_.id=?
```

To me it looks pretty much like what Hibernate logged (see above). To be honest, I don't know what it should look like so it's hard for me to tell what's wrong.

**EDIT:** @fredt's answer suggested the `property` column of the `number_matching_rule` tables was not of type `varchar`. The following screenshot from the HSQL Database Manager shows is actually is `varchar`.

[image]

Comment: You need to find out and report the SQL query that is generated by Spring and fails to compile. One way is to run HSQLDB in Server mode with `quiet=false` and check the queries that are submitted to the server.

Comment: Thanks, @fredt. Please check the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is raised in one of the subqueries that contain UNION ALL and is related to the type of the columns named `property` in the tables such as `number_matching_rule`. The first SELECT defines the type as `varchar(100)` and the types of the table column named `property` is not string (VARCHAR etc.).

For example:

```
select id, mode, cast(null as varchar(100)) as property, cast(null as int) as value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 1 as clazz_ from composite_matching_rule 
union all 
select id, mode, property, value, cast(null as boolean) as ignore_case, 2 as clazz_ from number_matching_rule 
union all 
select id, mode, property, value, ignore_case, 3 as clazz_ from string_matching_rule
```

Check the generated tables and see what SQL type is used for the `property` columns. Also check the other columns for type compatibility.

If the query was hand written, a cast such as `CAST(property AS VARCHAR(100))` would convert the column to the required type.

Edit:

You can check the query in DatabaseManager with:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select trainingre0_.id ...
```

If the exception is thrown, try the two subqueries that contain unions separately and simplify until you find which columns cause the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I attached a screenshot to the original post that proves the `property` column is of type `varchar`. If I understood correctly, you suspected that wasn't the case. The other colums in the `number_matching_rule` table are: ID (varchar), MODE (varchar), VALUE (DOUBLE). `string_matching_rule` has ID (varchar), IGNORE_CASE (boolean), MODE (varchar), PROPERTY (varchar), VALUE (varchar). The `value` column in the two tables are different. Would that be the cause?